# Calculate the grades of Subject In c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int PF, ICT, ENG;
    float avergemarks;

    cout << "enter the PF marks:";
    cin >> PF;
    cout << "enter the ICT marks:";
    cin >> ICT;
    cout << "enter the ENG marks:";
    cin >> ENG;
    avergemarks = (PF + ICT + ENG) / 3;
    cout << "the avergemarks is:" << avergemarks << endl;

    if (avergemarks >= 80 && avergemarks <= 85) {
        cout << "your grade is A" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 80 && avergemarks <= 75) {
        cout << "your grade is B+" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 75 && avergemarks <= 70) {
        cout << "your grade is B" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 70 && avergemarks <= 65) {
        cout << "your grade is C+" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 65 && avergemarks <= 60) {
        cout << "your grade is C" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 60 && avergemarks <= 55) {
        cout << "your grade is D" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 55 && avergemarks <= 50) {
        cout << "your grade is F" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 50 && avergemarks <= 45) {
        cout << "invalide avergemarks";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

You see the code in which I am find the grades of subject. When the output are print in console and I give him the number that user demand... When I give him three subject numbers, number-wise like 85, 85 and 85... The output are that thing *"the averagemarks is =85 and your grade is A."* But when I am giving that number like 60, 60 and 60 and want this *"the avergemarks is =60 and your grade is C"* but it does not give me that output it simple print *"the averagemarks is =60 "*...

So how would I solve this problem?

Comment: No number is 80 or larger and 75 or smaller. No number is 75 or larger and 70 or smaller. No number is 70or larger and 65 or smaller. No number is 65 or larger and 60 or smaller. No number is 60 or larger and 55 or smaller. No number is 55 or larger and 50 or smaller. No number is 50 or larger and 45 or smaller.

Comment: I highly recommend searching the internet for "c++ grade calculator".  This is a common assignment and probably a duplicate on SO.  Always search first before posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: @MikeCAT My answer is technically like your comment, but with more elaborated explanation. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I disagree with your recommendation. Trying to find the problem in the own code is the right way for learning. Your recommendation is the right way for earning money.

Comment: BTW, your average should be "/3.0" otherwise it is integer division.

Comment: @Yunnosch:  in the industry, we search for similar programs (that work) and compare ours to theirs (when we have nobody to review or the debugger is not available).  Also, is StackOverflow making money by storing duplicates?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews "Also, is StackOverflow making money by storing duplicates?" Yes I think so. Need an explanation?

Comment: This should **not** have been closed. It's reproducible, and a result of an error in logic, not simple typos. Worse, the advice in the existing answers is open to considerable improvement.

Comment: I have undone the last edit. I do not get your idea behind editing a (closed but answered) question into a different one. Please don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've combined the conditions when checking the boundaries so that the boundary checks will always be `false`.

`avergemarks >= 80 && avergemarks <= 75` - No `avergemarks` can be greater than or
equal to 80 **and** 75 or less at the same time.

This type of filter can be simplified by just checking one condition. If the previous
check has returned `false`, you know the number must be lower than what was checked there.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std::cout, std::endl;

    float avergemarks = 60.f;   // the result of your calculation

    cout << "the avergemarks is:" << avergemarks << endl;

    if (avergemarks < 50 || avergemarks > 85) { // check if it's out of the valid range
        cout << "invalid avergemarks";
    }
    // here follows a top-down filter using only one condition:
    else if (avergemarks >= 80) { // you know it's not above 85, so no need to test
        cout << "your grade is A" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 75) { // you know it's not 80 or above, so no need to test
        cout << "your grade is B+" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 70) { // you know it's not 75 or above, so no need to test
        cout << "your grade is B" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 65) { // you know it's not 70 or above, so no need to test
        cout << "your grade is C+" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 60) { // you know it's not 65 or above, so no need to test
        cout << "your grade is C" << endl;
    }
    else if (avergemarks >= 55) { // you know it's not 60 or above, so no need to test
        cout << "your grade is D" << endl;
    }
    else {                        // it must be in the range [50, 55), so no need to test
        cout << "your grade is F" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The number 80 does match this condition:

```
if(avergemarks>=80&&avergemarks<=85)
```

Because you have the lower treshold at the left of `&&` and compare it with `>=` and analog on the right of the `&&`, just reversed appropriatly.

But you have not applied that sensible pattern to any of the other conditions.
There you have the higher treshold on the left and the lower on the right, without reversing the operators appropriatly. That is why only the number 80..85 match a condition, the first one. All other cannot be passed by any number.

Make all conditions like the first one "lower treshold lower than and higher treshold higher than".

Answer (score 1):

your condition is always false, try to fix it to be like this

```
else if (avergemarks <= 80 && avergemarks >= 75) {
    cout << "your grade is B+" << endl;
}
.
.
.
else if (avergemarks <= 50 && avergemarks >= 45) {
    cout << "invalide avergemarks";
}
```

also you can store the grade char in variable and print it to make your code more elegant